# Is "the reals" a slang term for $\mathbb{R}^d$ where the variable $d = 1$?

Tags: notation, terminology

Often times I see people referring to certain functions as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to "the reals", are they referring to $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d = 1$?

Sorry for the potentially trivial question, as you can probably tell, I am still a student and very new to upper level mathematics.

Comment: Yes, to $\mathbb{R}^e$, where $e=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

”The reals" are indeed the real numbers, though I don't know if I'd call it a slang term.

Comment: In [some instances](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2613) it may be considered slang :)

Comment: I've never heard " $R$ to the 1$"  spoken.  If you say it, someone will likely ask, "Do you mean the reals?" :)